# GDB maintenance of muliple editors without ArcSDE

Tags: arcgis-10.1, arcgis-desktop, data, esri-geodatabase, metadata

I'm working with ArcGIS 10.1 SP1. I have finished 18 months of collecting data and digitization and built an impressive GDB with a lot of tables, relationship classes and 100 feature classes. Now i need to deliver it to the costumer. The GDB need to be updated twice a year by me and the customer can make some changes at tables but not at feature classes.
What are the best practices for GDB maintenance ? I thought about editor tracking and using complex relationship classes. More ideas are most welcome.
Thanks a lot, Geog

Comment: editor tracking would have to be your own db programming because it requires sde also.

Comment: Thanks Brad, let me focus my question - Is there a way to imitate versions Synchronization and replicas without ArcSDE ?

Comment: Some DBS have or support their own or 3rd party replication scenarios.

Comment: But they would mostly all be non spatial centric.  If you are planning an OTC or non esri spatial data type you might not have too much trouble with that. But once you step into the esri court it is tough to manage the benefits and not get caught in with the flow.  For instance. You can actually have an sde database and never install it. You get some benefit but can't do other ogc functions. With some more requirements and functional description someone may be able to help with stack options and tool possibilities.

Comment: Why without ArcSDE? Are you aware of [ArcSDE Personal Geodatabases](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/A_comparison_of_geodatabase_types/003n00000024000000/)? Included in ArcGIS for Desktop Standard und Advanced (formerly ArcEditor and ArcInfo) license level without additional license fee. There are some limitations (SQL Server Express, only one CPU core, 4 GB Maximum total data size …)

Comment: I wasn't aware of this - are you sure ? thanks a lot Geog

Comment: ArcSDE Personal Geodatabases have some limitations.  They support multiuser editing and replication. I'm not sure if they support all types of replication.

Comment: I created new Personal GDB and all the options for "Distributes Geodatabase" are grey, are you sure ?

Comment: You need a Personal ArcSDE Geodatabase, not a Personal Geodatabase - see my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why without ArcSDE? Are you aware of [ArcSDE Personal Geodatabases](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/A_comparison_of_geodatabase_types/003n00000024000000/)?

ArcSDE Personal Geodatabases are included in ArcGIS for Desktop Standard and Advanced (formerly ArcEditor and ArcInfo) license level without additional license fee. I am talking about **ArcSDE Personal Geodatabases**. I am **not** taking about **Personal Geodatabases**. Sometimes ArcSDE Personal Geodatabases are also called **ArcSDE for SQL Server Express**.

ArcSDE Personal Geodatabases are “multiuser Geodatabases”. They support multiuser editing, versioning and replication.

ArcSDE Personal  has limitations:

- maximum 4 gigabytes of storage per database
- 1 editor at a time
- 1 CPU core
- only Server Express 2005 (bundled within the ArcGIS Desktop
  installation package)

Here is a [good summary of the features  and limitations of ArcSDE Personal including a tutorial](http://esri.ca/en/content/replication-arcsde-personal-and-arcsde-workgroup).